# Selenium, dynamic content, chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to understand how to scrape some dynamic webpages,
but I'm unable to get it to work.

(The page I'm currently playing with is betfair.com, which on their live betting
soccer page have a dynamic match statistics page. To see it in action, go to 
betfair.com->Odds->LiveBetting, click on any soccer match.)

It is embedded inside two iframes, which I can access using:

```
frame1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@class, "player")]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame1)

frame2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@id, "playerFrame")]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame2)
```

I get an iframe back and can switch to it. So far so good. 
However, when I now try to use 'browser' for anything,
I get no response what so ever.

Is there anything else one need to do in order to read form the content?
I'm trying something like:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'in-game-stats')]")
```

The inner iframe above does contain the id. Also, if I try the steps above manual using chrome dev tools it does work. Any clues on why I get no answer to the above? Do I need to wait for something before it becomes available?

Comment: If this doesn't help, try posting the error(s) you're seeing and more help will likely come. For now, try `browser.switch_to.default_content()` after switching to a new window or frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third iframe underneath your `frame2`, select that before requesting for `in-game-stats`. All together,

```
frame1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@class, "player")]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame1)

frame2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@id, "playerFrame")]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame2)
```

You can try to get a better way of identifying this last iframe, here I am going to index it as the first iframe under iframe2.

```
frame3 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[1]')
browser.switch_to.frame(frame3)
```

Now you can get the node that you were looking for:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'in-game-stats')]")
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I have missed that?